# Python: Interacting object attributes

Tags: python, class, object, scope

I would like to write a model, in which different classes - stored in different files - are exchanging information.

For example, I have a main-file that will eventually execute the model

```
--main.py

from solution import Solver

solver = Solver()

solver.create()
```

There also two more files/classes that should later exchange information:

```
--solution.py
from grid import Remap
remap = Remap()

class Solver:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.solve = 4

    def create( self ): 
        remap.method1( )

        self.solve += remap.x+remap.y
        print self.solve

--grid.py
class Remap:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def method1( self ):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 2
```

This works so far and seems to be quite easy.

Now I would like to add another method to grid.py/Remap that uses the current attribute *solve* from the other class *Solver*. For example:

```
--grid.py
class Remap:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def method1( self ):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 2

    def method2( self ):
        self.x = ?????.solve
```

But how do I get the updated attribute from one class into another one, which are depending on each other, and avoid circular dependencies. Do I have to use external global classes (do they actually exist in Python?)?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what this code is supposed to be doing? Could you make the `Solver` object an *argument* to `Remap.method2()`?

Comment: I actually want to create an object that can be applied to different class. In C++ there is the possibility to declare an instance as extern in the header file, "extern Solver * solver;". I guess that is what I want to do in Python?!

Comment: That doesn't really explain much - could you provide less abstract examples of usage?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Solver` is accessing `remap` it should just pass itself into the `remap`:

```
class Solver:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.solve = 4
        self.remap.solver = self
```

and then `remap` can use it:

```
class Remap:
    def method2( self ):
        self.x = self.solver.solve
```